# Why does Mapbox Studio deform my polygon layers?

Tags: polygon, web-mapping, vector-tiles, mapbox-studio

I'm uploading perfect squares to Mapbox Studio, either .shp or .geojson, and the resulting layers are stretched or otherwise deformed.

Here are my polygons as seen in QGIS, EPSG:3857. They are all 50*50 meters, exactly orthogonal.
[image]

After loading them into Mapbox Studio they remain orthogonal, yet some end up getting stretched like north-south in this example, but there are also east-west stretching.
[image]

An even worse kind of deformation happens if the polygons are askew.

Here are the original polygons:
[image]

And the deformed ones in Mapbox Studio
[image]

Zooming in, you can see another deformation.
[image]

I tend to believe this is some tiling issue, where the polygons cross webmap tiles incorrectly, but have not managed to find the cause.

Has anyone encountered such a thing or knows a what to resolve the issue?

Comment: a 50m square in 3857 is probably not a square in which ever projection map box is using, or they are not really in 3857. Please include the WKT or JSON that describes one

Comment: Could it be an artifact of a 3D view snapping to the ground elevation?